# Reading content of zip using JSZip

Tags: javascript, unzip, jszip

I am uploading a zip folder and trying to read its XML file. The function can read the zip using JSZip but unable to retrieve the content of XML file.

**readasText** needs a blob object, I tried different things but it always gives type error.

```
  upload: function (e) {
                $("#fullPath").val(e.files[0].name);
                if ($.browser.msie == undefined || ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 10) == false) {
                    $("#fullPath").val(e.files[0].name);

                    var zipFile = new JSZip();
                    zipFile.loadAsync(e.files[0].rawFile)
                    .then(function(zip) {

                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsText(zip.files);// type error: dont know how to access the xml file 
                        reader.onloadend = function () {
                            GetValueFile(reader.result);
                        }                           
                    });                                    
                }
            }
```

I want to give the XML result to the **GetvalueFile** function 
The file object is inside **zip.files** but I'm unable to retrive it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same problem

```
zip.files['test1.xml'].async("string")// gives the content of xml
```

It returns a promise which can be used to trigger further functions

```
            .then(function(zip) {

                zip.files['test1.xml'].async("string")
                .then(function (data) {
                        GetValueFile(data);                         

                    });                                             
            });
```